# Protobuf parsing CPU time much less than wall-clock time

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deserialization, protocol-buffers

TL;DR: I found one of my program, which doesn't take any IO and little locking; CPU time only takes 80% of the wall-clock time.
I'm not sure how to explain that, and how to debug?

Context:

I did a `perf` and found my program is bottleneck-ed at a protobuf message deserialization (specifically, [tensorflow example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto)), which takes 35% of my CPU time.

Reading through tensorflow's code, I found they customized protobuf deserialization logic, which I think is for performance optimization.
Code pointer here: https://gitent.corp.nuro.team/Nuro-ai/tensorflow/blob/729d17bab0c77fd1db75031eec7f3ea119bb7e3d/tensorflow/core/util/example_proto_fast_parsing.cc#L586

I tried to mimic its logic, and made my own implementation.
From a high-level, it's getting a vector of <feature-key, serialized feature>.

What I did different from general protobuf deserialization is:

- Skip string lists, since I'm not sure it's not needed for my ML training jobs;
- Use multiple threads for parallelize serialized features' deserialization.

My benchmark result looks like such

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                                      Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_protobuf_parallel_deserialization/iterations:500          116 ms         93.9 ms          500
BM_protobuf_raw_deserialization/iterations:500        116 ms          116 ms          500
```

Comment: When CPU time is lower than wall-clock time, then your process is blocked for some amount of the time, for instance waiting for syscall, mutex etc. The time spent blocked is counted as wall-clock time but not CPU time.

Comment: You could try running your benchmark with different work sizes to determine if your problem is too small for parallelization to payoff. Larger work sizes should behave better in parallel (the overhead of parallelization gets spread out over more entries).